# Trying to test if next function was called on router

Tags: javascript, express

i don't know if the questions is very clear, but probably looking at the code you'll understand.

i'm trying to see if the next() function was called on my router.

But everytime i use the debugger, i watch that the next i passed as a stub to my router don't get on my router as a stub, looks like it get lost on the way. If i extract the callback from the router and exports it separately, it works just fine. But i didn't want to separate things and export them.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mostReadRouter = express.Router();
const mostReadBackEnd = require('../services/most-read-back-end');
const translateMostReadList = require('../services/most-read-service');

mostReadRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    let mostReadUrl = req.query.most_read_url;

    if (!mostReadUrl) {
        logger.error('param most_read_url is required');
        res.status(400).send('param most_read_url is required');
        return;
    }

    let sendSucces = mostRead => {
        logger.info(`sending most read list for url: ${mostReadUrl}`);
        res.json(mostRead);
    };

    let sendError = error => {
        if (isNotFoundError(error)) {
            next();
        } else {
            next(error);
        }
    };

    mostReadBackEnd
        .getMostReadList(mostReadUrl)
        .then(translateMostReadList, sendError)
        .then(sendSucces, sendError)
        .catch(sendError);
});

module.exports = mostReadRouter;
```

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const {expect} = chai;
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
const proxyQuire = require('proxyquire');
const statusStub = sandbox.stub();
const sendStub = sandbox.stub();
const getMostReadListStub = sandbox.stub();
const translateStub = sandbox.stub();
const jsonStub = sandbox.stub();
const thenStub = sandbox.stub();
process.env.CONFIGURATOR_API = 'xpto';


const router = proxyQuire('../../app/routes/most-read-router', {
    '../services/most-read-back-end': {
        getMostReadList: getMostReadListStub
    },
    '../services/most-read-service': {
        translate: translateStub
    }
});

describe('MostReadRouter', () => {
    afterEach(() => sandbox.reset());

    describe('#get(request,response,next)', () => {
        it.only('should call next() when getMostReadList does not work` ', async () => {
            
            getMostReadListStub.rejects(new Error('the error'));

            let req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/',
                query: {
                    most_read_url: 'http://beatiful_url.com'
                }
            };

            let res = {
                json: jsonStub
            };

            let next = sandbox.stub();
            

            await router(req, res, next);

            expect(next).to.be.calledOnce;
        });
    })
});
```